# How do I make sure the zoom doesn't go below zero and avoid the zoomed points touching the y and z axis? d3.zoom v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3.js. I am stuck of the following concepts:

I couldn't find examples where this is done in D3.js V4 and I am not sure how to navigate it.

1. To limit the zoom from going **beyond zero** I would like to use the minimum of the zoom as ZERO. I am not sure how to do this in scatter plot. 
   [image]
2. To avoid the zoomed points touching the y and z axis. I would like the points to fade or disappear when it touches the axis areas. 
   [image]

Here is my code

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 750 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xMax = d3.max(graphdata, function(d) { return d["x"]; }),
          yMax = d3.max(graphdata, function(d) { return d["y"]; });
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([0, xMax]).nice();

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, yMax]).nice();
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale);
var yTicks = 5
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(yScale);

var svg = d3.select("#plotspace").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "plot")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



// create a clipping region
svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


var gX = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .call(xAxis);


var gY= svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .call(yAxis
        );
        
var bubble = svg.selectAll('.bubble')
        .data(graphdata)
    .enter().append('path')
        .attr('class', 'bubble')
         .attr("d", d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCircle).size(30))
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + xScale(d["x"]) + "," + yScale(d["y"]) + ")"; })
        .attr('r', 3.5 )
        .attr('fill-opacity',0.7)
        .style('fill','blue');

bubble.append('title')
    .attr('x', 3.5 )
    .text(keys[0]);

// Pan and zoom
var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([.5, 20])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("pointer-events", "all")
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
      .call(zoom);

function zoomed() {


    var new_xScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale);
    var new_yScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yScale);

    gX.call(xAxis.scale(new_xScale));
    gY.call(yAxis.scale(new_yScale));
    bubble.data(graphdata)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + new_xScale(d["x"]) + "," + new_yScale(d["y"]) + ")"; })
      
      }
```

Comment: To prevent dots from appearing outside the axis I would add a [clippath](http://www.d3noob.org/2015/07/clipped-paths-in-d3js-aka-clippath.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue, negative numbers, is a result of allowing a zoom out from the initial zoom state. If the scales already hold all the data (since you dynamically create the scales), you should never have to zoom out from this zoom level. Zooming out from the initial zoom creates a plot area greater than the translate extent, this is causing negative values to appear in the scale. Try:

```
zoom.scaleExtent([1,4]);
```

That fixes the negative numbers, but you can still have overflow within those translate extents because you aren't using a clip path correctly.

You currently use one `g` called `svg` to plot points and draw axes, but you don't want to apply a clip area to this `g`, as the axes are outside of where you wish to draw the points. Instead, you could create a new `g` for the points only, and apply the plot area to that `g` with `g.attr('clip-path','url(#id)');`. Below I call that `g` `plotArea` and demonstrate these two changes:

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 750 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
var graphdata = d3.range(200).map(function(d) {
  return {x: d3.randomLogNormal()(), y: d3.randomLogNormal()()}
})    

var xMax = d3.max(graphdata, function(d) { return d["x"]; }),
    yMax = d3.max(graphdata, function(d) { return d["y"]; });
    
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([0, xMax]).nice();

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, yMax]);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale);
var yTicks = 5
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(yScale);

var svg = d3.select("#plotspace").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "plot")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// create a clipping region
svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
    
var plotArea = svg.append("g") // we don't want to clip the axes.    
  .attr("clip-path","url(#clip)");

var gX = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .call(xAxis);


var gY= svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .call(yAxis
        );
        
var bubble = plotArea.selectAll('.bubble') // add to clipped area.
    .data(graphdata)
    .enter().append('path')
    .attr('class', 'bubble')
    .attr("d", d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCircle).size(30))
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + xScale(d["x"]) + "," + yScale(d["y"]) + ")"; })
    .attr('r', 3.5 )
    .attr('fill-opacity',0.7)
    .style('fill','blue')
    
    

// Pan and zoom
var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 20])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("pointer-events", "all")
      .call(zoom);

function zoomed() {

    var new_xScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale);
    var new_yScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yScale);

    gX.call(xAxis.scale(new_xScale));
    gY.call(yAxis.scale(new_yScale));
    bubble.data(graphdata)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + new_xScale(d["x"]) + "," + new_yScale(d["y"]) + ")"; })
      
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="plotspace"></div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much! for the precise and clear explanation